# node.js simply does not run

Tags: node.js

I installed and ran node.js just fine on my mac, but even if I do this on windows

```
chdir c:\testfolder
node example.js
```

then I get this error:

```
node.js:201
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
Error: Cannot find module 'c:\testfolder\example.js'

at Function._resolveFilename <module.js:322:11>
at Function._load <module.js:299:25>
at Array.0 <module.js:499:10>
at EventEmitter._tickCallback <node.js:192:40>
```

I'm only even trying to run the example code on the nodejs website:

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
```

I don't understand, that file DOES exist!

Comment: How did you install Node.js and in what shell are you running it under Windows? (cmd.exe, command.com, Cygwin, Git Bash, PowerShell, some shell I'm not aware of?) I've never run into the issue you're mentioning on Windows, Mac, or Linux.

Comment: Are you certain that the file exists... I hate to ask if you didn't mess up the file extension or something? Try running this http://dl.dropbox.com/u/17781372/example.js - installed node just 5 minutes ago on my windows box and this runs fine.

Comment: @DavidEllis I just used the Windows installer, I'm using cmd.exe (I even tried right clicking and running as Administrator)

Comment: @MattEsch Esch I know I must look crazy given the error but the file does exist. I get the same error on yours as well.

Comment: @DavidEllis my path: C:\Users\Smith>echo %PATH%
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x8
6)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\
Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;c:\Program Fil
es (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;c:\Program Files (x86)\Common File
s\Roxio Shared\DLLShared\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Roxio Shared\12.0\
DLLShared\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Users\Smith\AppData\
Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\

Comment: @JasonFreitas it does not work unfortunately. For some reason if I type just "node" and hit enter I can do normal javascript commands, but it just cant find any of these files :(

Comment: Nothing out of the ordinary with that path. Can you finally run a ``dir /w`` on the directory where the file is located? This error makes absolutely no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely your file is not named example.js, but example.js.txt if you created it using notepad, and it is not turned on your machine to show file extensions for known file types :)

You will be able to see your real file name when you type: `chdir c:\testfolder` and then `dir`

Comment: Nope, not the case I'm afraid.

Comment: Then, I'm not sure what else can be the case. Can you show us what "dir" command says"? Anyway, I really think that in this case (with the symptoms you are reporting) nothing else can be a problem but that your file is not named example.js but something different (most likely example.js.txt).

Comment: It's not called .js.txt, I am 1000% sure of that :P

Comment: try downloading and installing the newest version then...I've just did that and it works perfectly fine. No other ideas from me.